Riemann integral depends on the coordinates system
I'm studying an introduction on the theory of integration on manifolds, and i found an observation on 'introduction to manifolds' of W.Tu that i didn't understand.
In particular:

When we speak of rectangle in $\mathbb{R^n}$ we have already tacitly chosen $n$ coordinates axes, with coordinates $x^1,..,x^n$. Thus, the definition of a Riemanni integral depends on the coordinates $x^1,..,x^n$

I'm not sure that i really understand the point. The 'only' coordinates-dependence is the orientation of the coordinate system itself?

The Riemann integral is defined in terms of a rectangular grid, which, in turn, is dependent on the coordinate system. I do not know what you mean by "the orientation of the coordinate system."
